# Unable to do telnet to php socket code

Tags: php, sockets, telnet

I created a php program to listen to a port.Here is the php code

```
<?php

if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
    die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}
echo "Socket created \n";


if( !socket_bind($sock, "192.168.0.177" , 5060) )
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
    die("Could not bind socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}
echo "Socket bind OK \n";

while(1)
{
    echo "Waiting for data ... \n";

    $r = socket_recvfrom($sock, $buf, 512, 0, $remote_ip, $remote_port);

    echo $buf;
}

?>
```

But when i do `telnet 192.168.0.177 5060` i get message

```
Could not open connection to the host on port 5060
```

I checked the telnet service and its running fine.

Comment: Does `telnet 127.0.0.1 5060` work ?

Comment: That also doesn't work

Comment: Are you accessing it from the server that has created socket ?

Comment: well i'm checking it from the same server which is running the php code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you open an UDP socket, and `telnet` uses TCP.

Comment: @iBlue Are you sure that you want UDP and not TCP?

Comment: @iBlue You could use something like [netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) possibly. Or write your own client of course.